# Refactoring a SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've written this SQL Script:

```
    DECLARE @location geography  
    DECLARE @radius int  

    SET @location = (SELECT Location FROM Hydrants WHERE HydrantId = 2)  
    SET @radius = (SELECT Radius FROM Hydrants WHERE HydrantId = 2)  

    SELECT * 
    FROM Sites 
    WHERE @location.STDistance(location) < @radius 
    ORDER BY SiteId ASC
```

I did this to refactor it

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sites, Hydrants 
Inner Join Hydrants.Location.STDistance(Sites.Location) < Hydrants.Radius  
WHERE Hydrants.HydrantId = 2 
ORDER BY Sites.SiteId ASC;
```

but without luck.

Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: What is the problem? My mind reading device is on the fritz today.

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to include the specific RDBMS you're using.  Is this SQL Server, if so, what version?

Comment: @DanNewhouse I think only SQL Server has the `geography` data type, starting with 2K8.

Comment: I'm working with SQL Server ver. 2008 r2

Comment: Might be better over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know the geographic features of sql 2008 but when seeing your code, the following might work:

```
SELECT
    Sites.*
FROM Sites
INNER JOIN Hydrants
    ON Hydrants.Location.STDistance(Sites.location) < Hydrants.Radius
WHERE Hydrants.HydrantId = 2 
ORDER BY Sites.SiteId ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives me both sites and hydrants in the same line. I only need the sites in the given radius from the hydrants.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with the geography types, but this is the correct syntax of a join that does the same as your original query;

```
SELECT Sites.*
FROM Sites 
JOIN Hydrants 
  ON Hydrants.Location.STDistance(Sites.Location) < Hydrants.Radius  
WHERE Hydrants.HydrantId = 2 
ORDER BY Sites.SiteId ASC;
```